# How do I post an image from the mobile site?

Tags: support, images, mobile-web

I use [Chrome on Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_for_Android). I can't find a way to add an image in the answer box. No icon for attaching images. How can I do that?

Comment: You can add with stack exchange android application. Also it's not right place for asking that kind of questions. Use http://meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: @NafizBayındır It's perfectly fine to ask for support on child metas, though I agree Meta.SE might already have an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to use a mobile supported upload image facility like `imgur.com` (this is what Stack Exchange also uses) and once you have uploaded it, you can any way get the uploaded URL.

Use the markdown syntax to type out the URL as an image:

```
![alt text](url here)
```

Hope this is what you are expecting. But if this isn't, please let me know in comments. Also I believe you might need to have some minimum rep to add images, add multiple images.

Imgur allows you to upload stuff from your device this way:

[image]